# How to create an interaction in a button in discord.js?

Tags: node.js, discord.js

how to do i create an interaction of a click of a button in discord.js here is the code of the button without the interaction

```
const discord = require('discord.js');

module.exports = {
  name: 'test',
  description: '124',
  category: 'test-18293',
  aliases: [''],
  run: async (client, message, args, prefix, config) => {
  client.api.channels(message.channel.id).messages.post({
    data: {
    "content": "This is an example!",
    "components": [
        {
            "type": 1,
            "components": [
                {
                    "type": 2,
                    "label": "Primary",
                    "style": 1,
                    "custom_id": "sdvpvodsif"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
  });
 }
}
```

but the problem is I don't know how to create an interaction on click of the button, can you guys help me :( thank you!

Comment: This is a very general question and I think no one can explain it to you. You need to search for it on your own.

Comment: *"create an interaction"* - so how the bot receives it, or tries to create an "artificial" interaction?

Answer (score 3):

If you want to do something when a button is clicked, you would need to create a `messageComponentCollector` in the channel where you have sent the buttons by using `message.channel.createMessageComponentCollector`. You would also need to specify a few options such as how much time the collector must be valid for and how many people can click on the button. You can also pass in a filter to make sure that only the person you want to click the button can click it.

The code goes something like this:

```js
const filter = (click) => click.user.id === message.author.id
const collector = message.channel.createMessageComponentCollector({
    max: "1", // The number of times a user can click on the button
    time: "10000", // The amount of time the collector is valid for in milliseconds,
    filter // Add the filter
});

collector.on("collect", (interaction) => {
    interaction.reply("Clicked!"); // Run a piece of code when the user clicks on the button
});

collector.on("end", (collected) => {
    console.log(`Collected ${collected.size} clicks`); // Run a piece of code when the collector ends
});
```