# How to detect and perform an action from a button click on a channel discord.js

Tags: javascript, discord.js

I did read the documentation about buttons on discord [here](https://discordjs.guide/interactions/buttons.html#the-interactioncreate-event). I also checked the message component collector, but I still couldn't make it work.

I'm trying to do an action/response when a button from a discord bot embed message which has a button is clicked. The button came from a discord bot, which I didn't make. I just need my own bot to respond to it.

1. Embed with 1 button appears from a bot.
2. Click the button.
3. Then do something.

So far, I did try this to see if I can get the property details of the embed button but nothing's happening:

```
client.on('interactionCreate', async interaction =>{
    if (!interaction.isButton()) return;
    console.log(interaction);
})
```

Tried this too:

```
    client.on('interactionCreate', async interaction =>{
      if (interaction.isButton()){
      console.log(interaction);
    } else{
      console.log("Error happened.");
    }
    })
```

Comment: What errors do you get when you click on the button? None? Did you check actual console log as you are obviously doing `console.log`? You can't expect for bot to send message in channel if you're just doing `console.log`

Comment: sorry, i edited the code. yes, i'm trying it on console for now. There's no output. I trigger the bot  then click the button but nothing's happening on the console.

Comment: Check my posted answer @user874737

Comment: hello i made this work. I created my own embed with a button on my own bot. it works fine. i can see interaction logs. however, there are no console logs when i try to listen for other bots like mee6. that's what i need help on. still trying to figure out.

Comment: Hey @user874737 did you solve this by now? I am very insterested in that feature, since we had events by apollo bot deleted and wanted to figure out who is pressing the delete button. I also went for the isButton check but see no logs in console as well.

I was wondering if we need to use collections like here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70707117/how-to-create-an-interaction-in-a-button-in-discord-js , but the post is old and i am not sure thats only for our own bots or in general :-/

Comment: Hello @Amanda, I listened to the messageUpdate instead. client.on("messageUpdate", (oldMsg, newMsg)). I checked the parts of the bot's message that never change to make sure that I'm listening to the right message, and then I set a condition that if certain parts of the old message gets edited/update to this specific value then do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the interaction is ONLY sent to an application that created it (A).
If I understand you correctly, you'd like to receive it from application B, your bot. So... you can't.

Comment: I removed the non-answering parts, for which you would need the commenting privilege and which anyway would not be appropriate inside the answer post.